# How to cast Jest SearchResult hits to domain object

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am using Jest to query Elasticsearch and so far it has been great. [Jest's documentation](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/README.md) says:

> Result can be cast to List of domain object;

... and shows this example:

```
SearchResult result = client.execute(search);
List<SearchResult.Hit<Article, Void>> hits = searchResult.getHits(Article.class);
// or
List<Article> articles = result.getSourceAsObjectList(Article.class);
```

`getSourceAsObjectList` is deprecated, and I am using:

```
List<SearchResult.Hit<ImmutableConceptDocument, Void>> concepts = result.getHits(ImmutableConceptDocument.class);
```

... Where `ImmutableConceptDocument` is an [immutables](http://immutables.github.io/) generated class - otherwise pretty straight forward POJO, with attributes named as I see under the `source` of my search results.

However, when I use the above line, I don't get the source properties mapped, I do get other details like `score`, `type`, `index` etc. mapped.

What am I missing? Does the domain class need to have specific Jest annotations or something like that?

I can't see any good examples in the unit tests too. [This one](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest-common/src/test/java/io/searchbox/core/SearchResultTest.java#L138-L153) maps to `Object.class` and that does not show me a mapping example.

Here is the immutable class:

```
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class EsConceptDocument {
    public abstract String term();
    public abstract Category type();
    public abstract List<String> synonyms();
}
```

... where `Category` is an enum type.

Comment: The domain class doesn't need any specific annotations (except if you're willing to deserialize Date objects). Can you show your `ImmutableConceptDocument` class?

Comment: Thanks. Added the class.

Comment: That's not `ImmutableConceptDocument` but probably its abstract super class ?

Comment: Ah, your comment highlighted the problem. Immutable makes the constructor private. I removed immutable annotation and wrote a POJO with a constructor and getters and got it working.

Comment: @arnab Hey, I have a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44557382/jest-elasticsearch-search-api-hits-mapping

Could you please help ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Val pointed out in the comments, this was because immutables.io makes the generated class' constructor private (and exposes a builder).

I removed immutable from this class and wrote a constructor and getters and it worked.