# Jest ElasticSearch Search API Hits mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm extremely new to elastic search

I'm trying to understanding the below code :

```
List<Hit<Talk, Void>> hits = result.getHits(Talk.class);
        for (Hit<Talk, Void> hit: hits) {
            Talk talk = hit.source;
            log.info(talk.getTitle());
        }
```

This is directly taken from : https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-java-clients-for-elasticsearch

My question is , how does Java know what field to map to what variable.

Essentially , how does Java know , say to match the property "title" to the member variable "title" of the Talk class.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page it mentions that the `Talk` class is a Bean.  Beans implement `Serializable`.  When `result.getHits` is called, notice how `Talk.class` object is passed into the method.  That means you are basically deserializing the hits into `Talk` instances.  With how the JEST `Hit` class is structured, that is how you access the `Talk` instances after they are deserialized from the Elastisearch response.

For more information on Beans, see here: [What is a JavaBean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295496/what-is-a-javabean-exactly)

Comment: so is it necessary to use a class which is a bean ? Could I instead just make my own class that implements Serializable ?
Thank you for the answer! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: A bean is just a set of criteria that a class needs to meet to be considered such.  So if you meet those criteria with any class you write, it is by definition a bean.  In other words, yes you can write your own class that implements Serializable, and if you meet the criteria in the question I linked, it should work.